# How can I program a while loop that waits for my input in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, methods, while-loop

My question is simple. What method can I use to tell my program that a button is pressed? I'm trying some codelines but its not really working (I tryed with isPressed). in my logs I can read the line --> TAMAÑO DEL CONTADOR: < the numbers until it reaches max.> before I can I even place a value, so I understand the loop doesnt wait for my inputs.

Here is my code:

```
public class navegador extends AppCompatActivity {

public String Sdat;
public EditText ET2;
int tam;

ArrayList<String> Medidas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navegador);

    ET2 = findViewById(R.id.ET1);
    Button bot = findViewById(R.id.bot);

    tam = getIntent().getIntExtra("numero",0);

    Medidas = new ArrayList<>();
    int contador = 0;

    System.out.println("TAMAÑO DEL ARRAY: "+ tam);

    while ( contador <= tam){

        System.out.println("TAMAÑO DEL CONTADOR: " + contador);

        bot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View bot) {
                if(bot.isPressed()){
                    MeterMedida();
                }
            }
        });
        contador++;

        if(contador == tam){

            Toast.makeText(this, "Distancia máxima alcanzada. Toca Crear tabla.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}

public void MeterMedida(){

    Sdat = ET2.getText().toString();
    Medidas.add(Sdat);
    ET2.setText("");

}

public void LanzarLista (View view){

    Intent A = new Intent(this, Lista.class);
    A.putStringArrayListExtra("Lista", Medidas);
    startActivity(A);
}
}
```

Thanks a lot, ask me for more information if you think you need it.

### EDIT

As usual, less is more, I removed the while, and contador variable, now it works like I wanted and its pretty much simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: why do you need a while loop?

Comment: @HasanBouTaam I need it to fill my arraylist of float values that the user introduces with an EditText one by one

Comment: When you set a listener, there is a loop run anyways. You don't need to make your own. You can put all your logic into the listener, and when that is triggered, you do what you need to do

Comment: I suggest that you learn about Android's event system. You never need to make a loop that waits for something to happen. Android already has this loop and there is always a way to register a function that will be called the thing happens that you want to respond to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need a `while` loop:**

```
    //a list to keep all the entered floats
    private List<Float> floats = new ArrayList<Float>();

    //each time you click the listener is invoked
    bot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View bot) {

                //every time the button is clicked, fill the current typed float


             floats.add(Float.parseFloat(ET2.getText().toString()));
             ET2.setText("");

        }
    });
```

Comment: aah, didnt know that, ok i removed the while and now works good. thank you

Comment: Great, if that helped accept the answer for others with same problem to know.

Answer (score 3):

You said that you wanted to tell your app when a button is pressed, do something. There's no need to use isPressed() method. Just do it like this.

```
 bot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View bot) {     
            //When you press this button (bot), codes here will be executed.
            MeterMedida();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, both comments are very useful. Im starting in this, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I’m not gonna give complete answer. Just a few hints for yourself to figure out.

1. Declare `int contador = 0;` in class level
2. Remove `while ( contador <= tam)`
3. Remove `if(bot.isPressed())`
4. Remove `contador++;` in your `onCreate`
5. Inside `MeterMedida()` check for `if(contador <= tam)`. If `true`, add to `ArrayList` and increment `contador`. Else show error `Toast`.